I am unable to understand the contradiction in below conversation between Sri Ram and Sri Hanuman
सीता कै अति बिपति बिसाला। बिनहिं कहें भलि दीनदयाला॥5॥
निमिष निमिष करुनानिधि जाहिं कलप सम बीति।
बेगि चलिअ प्रभु आनिअ भुज बल खल दल जीति॥31॥
सुनि सीता दु:ख प्रभु सुख अयना। भरि आए जल राजिव नयना॥
बचन कायँ मन मम गति जाही। सपनेहुँ बूझिअ बिपति कि ताही॥1॥
कह हनुमंत बिपति प्रभु सोई। जब तव सुमिरन भजन न होई॥
केतिक बात प्रभु जातुधान की। रिपुहि जीति आनिबी जानकी॥2॥
Here first Hanuman ji is saying about distress of maa sita.
Listning this sri ram also had tears
Then he says
बचन कायँ मन मम गति जाही। सपनेहुँ बूझिअ बिपति कि ताही
and finally Sri hanuman ji acknowledges
कह हनुमंत बिपति प्रभु सोई। जब तव सुमिरन भजन न होई॥
My confusion is even after reciting Ram naam all the time, how and why Sita ji was in sorrow.
How Hanuman ji got convinced that सीता कै अति बिपति बिसाला became कह हनुमंत बिपति प्रभु सोई। जब तव सुमिरन भजन न होई.
I am unable to understand this transition.

Can you pl add those verses in english letters also. I dont know what language that is and hindi to english google translator fails to translate.
